# Is there any way to alter a caller's voice just enough to make voice recognition impossible?

Tags: privacy, identity, smartphone

I did search and found this post:

[Is it possible to identify mobile phone user with voice recognition](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185752/is-it-possible-to-identify-mobile-phone-user-with-voice-recognition)

It does not answer my question, however.

Is there any way to alter a person's voice just enough to make the cell call unrecognizable with voice recognition techniques?

Comment: You could alter your voice during a call by using on of those apps from google store.call voice changer or something

Answer (score 1):

Sure. @VipulNair is right. There is a lot of such software.

Regarding "to make voice recognition impossible?":
It depends on the quality of the voice changer and the quality of the voice recognition software. The simple voice recognition software calculates a few statistical patterns and is easy to foul.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. Voice recognition software may identify you not only using the sound of your voice, but the words you use, the duration of pauses, how you the words are joined together. That features are difficult to a sound editor to change.

Currently there are software that can match a person to a text he wrote, mainly using the set of words used, and how they are used. Pair a Speech-to-Text with it, and you basically have the same thing, but for voice and not written text. You can garble the audio enough to foil the conversion, but the human on the other side will not be able to understand you too.

Comment: You are answering the not the question that was asked. You are describing the **speech recognition**, where as the question is about **voice recognition**. Voice recognition is about sound stream and identifying some patterns in this stream. It has nothing to do with recognizing words and matching them to texts. That's why I voted your answer down.

Comment: I consider the words you use and the pauses between them as features a software would use to identify you, and that would be more deterministic than the pitch or speed of your voice. Pitch and speed are trivially changed by any audio editor, but changing the words you used are not that trivial.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Speech recognition is much more powerful, much more precise and much more reliable. But the question is about voice, i.e. about frequencies, duration, volume.